# LWC Accordian Component labels

Tags: lightning-web-components, accordion

I'm pretty new to development in general, but I'm trying to implement an LWC (accordian) that pulls the label from 2 different fields within our SFDC. The issue that I'm having is that when I click on the "open all" or "collapse all", the labels on the accordian get set back undefined. I'm pretty sure I didn't follow the best practice here, but any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

I have the following (took out some details, but please let me know if this is unclear)

JS File

```
@track activeSections = [];
@track openSectionList = '';
@track comment = []
@wire(getCommentData, {recordId : '$recordId' })
    comments({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.comment = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else {
            this.comment = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
// iterate through arrays
    get labelValue(){
        this.showData1 = this.objectData.map(objectData => objectData.data1);
        this.showData2 = this.objectData.map(objectData => objectData.data2);
            this.label = (this.data1[i] + ' ' + this.data2[i]);
            i += 1;
        return this.label;
    }
    // toggle button
    handleSectionToggle(event) {
        this.openSectionList = event.detail.openSections.join(', ');
    }
    // expand all
    handleOpenAll(event) {
        this.activeSections = this.comment.map(comment => comment.data);
    }
    // collapse all
    handleCollapseAll(event) {
        this.activeSections = [];
    }
    
};
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={data}>
    <lightning-accordion
        allow-multiple-sections-open
        onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
        active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <div>
            <lightning-button onclick={handleOpenAll} label="Open All" title="openAll"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button onclick={handleCollapseAll} label="Collapse All" title="collapseAll"></lightning-button>
        </div>
            <template if:true={data}>
                <template for:each={data} for:item="item" for:index="i">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name={item.data} label={labelValue} key={data.data} class="accordian-class">
                        <p key={data.data}> {item.data} 
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                    </template>
            </template>
    </lightning-accordion>
</template>
</template>
```

Comment: not clear how you are populating `this.comment` or it's json structure assuming  it is an array of objects

Comment: Hi @glls, sorry about that, updated the code. I'm getting "comments" through the wire method and then checking if there's a response. If so I'm then assigning it to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all centers around the `getLabelValue` method.

A `getter` can't render different values for in a list.

Also, you have made a sort of `map` function that mixed into a standard `for` loop.

It's also not clear where you are putting `data` - it looks like you are adding it to the `comment` var, but you seem to still be trying to iterate `data` despite it not being stored anywhere.

Because you need a different label value for each element in your accordian, you need to add it to the data that you are iterating on.

Finally, since `data` is immutable, you need to change it to a mutable array so you can write your label information to it.

- Change your iterator in the template to iterate on `comment`.
- In the wire handler, assign data like this: `this.comment = Object.assign([],data);`
- Write your label to this array in a loop.

```
this.comment.forEach( c-> {
  c.label = (c.SomeValue + ' ' + c.SomeOtherValue);
});
```

You can do this just after assigning `this.comment`;

If you run into any problems, assign to a temporary array and iterate on that, finally assigning it to the `comment` array when done.

Finally, if `comment` is a list, you should call it `comments`

Comment: This led me the right way, thank you! Sorry about my messy code, really a novice here. Thanks for spending the time to walk me through this one.

Comment: No probs - I wasn't really able to provide the exact answer, but I'm glad that I could help a little.